# What should I do when my D3400 aperture is stuck no matter what lens I use?

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting, aperture

I have a D3400 and recently I haven't been able to change the aperture on any of my lenses in manual mode. I have lenses with aperture rings and if I set the aperture to anything below the largest aperture such as f/16 and put it on the camera, the aperture opens back up to f/1.4 by itself.

This problem just started. Every lens that I use is unable to change aperture. If I mount the lens, the aperture is forced wide open, even if it's set to f/16 on the lens. When I press the shutter it stays wide open. Whether I use the viewfinder or live view, the behavior is the same. And once I remove the lens, the lens closes back to f/16.

Comment: I don't have anything with an aperture ring that isn't a full manual lens, but my guess would be that the camera is 'in charge'. What happens if you mount the lens, set to f/16 then detach & remount? Additionally what happens if you mount another lens in between those events, with & without changing aperture from the camera?

Comment: What lenses? Did this just start or is it a problem that's been like that from when you got the camera?

Comment: This problem just started. Every lens that I use is unable to change aperture. If I mount the lens, the aperture is forced wide open, even if it's set to f/16 on the lens. And once I remove the lens, the lens closes back to f/16.

Comment: @ElvisMa - with the lens mounted and set on f/16 (but with the lens aperture wide open), what happens when you press the shutter?

Comment: Are you trying to change aperture when looking through the viewfinder, or are you using live view? Are you in photo mode, or movie mode?

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere The aperture still stays wide open

Comment: @scottbb I've tried changing the aperture when looking through the viewfinder and the live view, but the aperture still doesn't change.

Comment: Can you state specifically what model lenses you are using? You state in a [comment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109680/what-should-i-do-when-my-d3400-aperture-is-stuck-no-matter-what-lens-i-use#comment211428_109683) "I'm using old vintage lenses that don't communicate with the camera." But the behavior you describe in [another comment](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109680/what-should-i-do-when-my-d3400-aperture-is-stuck-no-matter-what-lens-i-use#comment211311_109680) indicates the lenses *are* communicating with the camera.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have not switched camera models recently? What camera mode are you trying to use? Photograph showing the mount side of the lenses would also be helpful.

Comment: What lenses are you using? If non-Nikon mount, what adapter(s)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ken](https://kenrockwell.com/nikon/d3400.htm), aperture ring compatibility was "missing" on the D3400, while the D3300 (and earlier) had some support for lenses with aperture rings.

I've used a D3200 with lenses with an aperture ring, but unless the aperture is set to the smallest (largest number), the camera gives an error message - and this only applies to lenses with at least partial support of automatic aperture. (In this case the lens will be wide open until the shutter is released or the preview button pressed.)

It sounds like this might no longer be the case on the D3400. The answer [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103116/nikon-d3400-aperture) might also be useful,

Comment: But I was able to use the aperture ring before today

Comment: @ElvisMa - How did you use it previously (ie. what did you do and what did you see)? The 3*** series doesn't have the rotating ring around the lens mount that engages with the aperture ring on the lens, and I've not been able to vary the aperture using the ring on the D3200 as I would with other (eg. D810) Nikons.

Comment: Previously, I was able to turn the aperture ring and I could see the image get darker or brighter through the live view.